# How to tell npm to build module on install with the parent project's dependencies?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, material-ui

I would like to get an explanation about the way npm modules getting build on install, I'll give an example:

When I'm taking a look on the [`material-ui` npm module sources on GitHub](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui), There's sources but there's no built files, when I take a look on my project `node_modules/material-ui` directory I can see that the directory contain only the built files (es5, uglify).

I'm trying to understand how that magic happens? I see that there's build script inside the `package.json` but there's nothing that tell npm to run it on install, what am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually modules don't get built on the client's machine, because that would take additional time and might fail because they are using an older version of Node.js that doesn't support the build tools, and of course the build tools would need to be installed as well, which would make the process even longer. Instead you build it before publishing. What is on GitHub is different from what is actually published to the npm registry. Most modules don't check in the built sources into GitHub (although some people prefer to).

Presumably `material-ui` does this process manually and just publishes the built sources, as seen in [Unpkg - material-ui](https://unpkg.com/material-ui@0.17.0/).

Some other packages like [redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux) use a `prepublish` hook, which builds the necessary sources just before it gets published when running `npm publish` ([Redux prepublish hook](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/f77923f55f7c7f282b6abd473a8edf5bad72a669/package.json#L28)), which reflects the published package as you can see in [Unpkg - Redux](https://unpkg.com/redux@3.6.0/). It's pretty close to the original source on GitHub but only contains the relevant files, including built files that are in its [.gitignore](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/f77923f55f7c7f282b6abd473a8edf5bad72a669/.gitignore#L4-L6) file. Because a lot of files are unnecessary to be published (e.g. the `test` directory, `rollup.config.js` etc.) and would only take up space on the client, you can specify [`files` in `package.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files) to only publish the listed files ([Redux files](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/f77923f55f7c7f282b6abd473a8edf5bad72a669/package.json#L10-L16)).

You just happened to have picked a quite confusing package with `material-ui` when it comes to publishing, whereas `redux` is a lot easier to understand.

Comment: Michael is correct, we publish the build (for the reasons given), and the process isn't _that_ complicated. `npm build` builds in the `build` directory, copies the relevant parts of the base `package.json` to a new one in `build`, and we publish from there. This leaves behind all the cruft and gives you a nice clean package.

Comment: Also keep in mind that if the build files are ignored with `.gitignore`, then npm will ignore them as well (thus, not publish them) unless they are manually unignored with `.npmignore`. Read the [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package) for details.